# kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, maven, out-of-memory, apache-kafka

I am trying to start a Kafka server using the following code:

```
public class MockKafkaServer {

    private static final String LOCALHOST = "127.0.0" + ".1";
    private static final int CONSUMER_TIMEOUT_MS = 5000;
    private static final int CONSUMER_BUFFER_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
    private static final int PRODUCER_SLEEP_INTERVAL = 100;

    private final KafkaServerStartable broker;
    private final MockZooKeeper mockZooKeeper;

    private KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]> kafkaProducer;
    private SimpleConsumer simpleConsumer;

    private final int port;


    public MockKafkaServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        this.mockZooKeeper = new MockZooKeeper();
        final int zkPort = mockZooKeeper.start();

        this.port = getAvailablePort();

        final File logDirectory = Files.createTempDir();
        logDirectory.deleteOnExit();

        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("zookeeper.connect", LOCALHOST + ":" + zkPort);
        properties.put("broker.id", "0");
        properties.put("num.partitions", "1");
        properties.put("host.name", "localhost");
        properties.put("port", String.valueOf(port));
        properties.put("log.dir", logDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
        properties.put("auto.create.topics.enable", "true");

        this.broker = new KafkaServerStartable(new KafkaConfig(properties));
    }

    public void start() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        broker.startup();
    }

    public void stop() {
        broker.shutdown();
        broker.awaitShutdown();
        mockZooKeeper.stop();
    }

   }
```

And the unit test cases call start() and stop() for every unit test case execution. What I observe is, after a few times of start and stop, I get the following error:

```
 7790 [main] FATAL kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable  - Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
    at kafka.log.SkimpyOffsetMap.<init>(OffsetMap.scala:44)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.<init>(LogCleaner.scala:196)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner$$anonfun$2.apply(LogCleaner.scala:86)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner$$anonfun$2.apply(LogCleaner.scala:86)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner.<init>(LogCleaner.scala:86)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createLogManager(KafkaServer.scala:647)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:209)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
    at com.viper.mockkafkaj.MockKafkaServer.start(MockKafkaServer.java:87)
    at com.viper.project.restj.RestControllerTest.setUp(RestControllerTest.java:68)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:261)
```

I tried setting the following values for Maven test plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-server -Xss128m -Xms64m -Xmx256m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=50 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So, even with Xmx set to 1024m, I get the OutOfMemoryError. Any help appreciated !

Comment: if it is linux try using `top` to track the memory consumption to know more about it.

Comment: Did you enable Kafka security? And what's Kafka version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out to be a issue with Kafka 0.10.2.0 with log cleaner thread using high memory by default. I set the following value and I do not see the heap space error anymore.

```
private static final long CLEANER_BUFFER_SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024L;

properties.put("log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size", CLEANER_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Comment: This solves OOM issue during kafka start up in my windows env. Added this on server.properties: log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size=2000000.